# Is there any way to reinstall windows 7 while keeping my programs there?

Tags: windows-7, windows, reinstall

Ok, I know this has been asked many times, however all the answers I've seen (even in my Google searches) all need the user to be able to boot onto windows. My current windows installation is corrupted and there is no way I can boot, not even into safe-mode, last good configuration etc...

My question is that giving the circumstance of being unable to boot into windows 7 is there a way to re-install windows keeping all programs intact? The reason being is that I have quite some software to re-install and too little time.

Thanks in advance

Comment: No;  If you are unable to boot you are unable to do the one method that would work.

Comment: @Ramhound Thanks for this. I also feel I should attribute this to you, so I think you should add this as an answer

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest you try booting from a windows 7 DVD and run the installer.

It may be able to repair your current installation.

While this is not quite a "reinstallation" per se, you may be able to restore your system to a working state, while keeping your programs intact.

See [this link](http://pcsupport.about.com/od/toolsofthetrade/ss/windows-7-startup-repair.htm) for detailed instructions.

Best of luck!

Comment: The type of repair the author requires can only be done if he can boot into Windows.  The method you describe would result in Windows being installed over the current installation instead of it an "in-place upgrade" installation being done.

Comment: @Kristian Maybe I wasn't clear enough in the question but I can't boot into Windows and repairing using the disks (normal way) doesn't help. This also means that I can't do an upgrade installation as I have to be able to boot on Windows.

Comment: @Ramhound the method I am describing is *not* installing over the current installation, it is a repair of the existing installation. So what you are saying is not true. I have done these types of repairs several times and they do indeed keep system settings and installed programs intact. I may, however, not have given the proper emphasis on this in my original answer. So I understand the confusion. If you follow the link I provided, you will see the exact method I was suggesting spelled out in full.

Comment: Yes;  I know the method;  It just can't be done without being within Windows.  I had an installation that wasn't able to repair itself.  **I have used the method before, but the different was, I was able to boot into Windows**.  When I attempted to determine if I could do it without being able to boot into Windows my research showed it wasn't possible.